# Javascript, how do I submit a form, then close the current window?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a popup login form. I want the form to submit, then close that popup window. How can I accomplish this? The window is currently set to close before the return for the function happens. Where does window.close() go in this case? Thank you for any help.

Form:

```
<form name="catseczoneform30738" onSubmit="return checkWholeForm30738(this)" method="post" action="https://redlakewalleye.worldsecuresystems.com/ZoneProcess.aspx?ZoneID=12695&Referrer={module_siteUrl,true,true}&OID={module_oid}&OTYPE={module_otype}">
            <div class="form">
              <div class="item">
                <label for="SZUsername">Username</label>
                <br />
                <input class="cat_textbox_small" type="text" name="Username" id="SZUsername" maxlength="255" />
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <label for="SZPassword">Password</label>
                <br />
                <input class="cat_textbox_small" type="password" name="Password" id="SZPassword" maxlength="255" autocomplete="off" />
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" id="RememberMe" />
                <label for="RememberMe">Remember Me</label>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <input class="cat_button" type="submit" value="Log in" />
                &nbsp;<a href="/_System/SystemPages/PasswordRetrieveRequest">Lost password?</a></div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/CatalystScripts/ValidationFunctions.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    function checkWholeForm30738(theForm){var why = "";
    if (theForm.Username) why += isEmpty(theForm.Username.value, "Username");
    if (theForm.Password) why += isEmpty(theForm.Password.value, "Password");
    if (why != ""){alert(why);
        return false;
        }
    theForm.submit();
    window.open('http://www.redlakewalleye.com/promotional/activation-form','_blank');
    window.close();
    return false;
    }
//]]>
       </script>            
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible the window.close() should be included as part of the server response to your submit event. If you include the window.close() as part of the submit on the form, it will cause your form to close before the submit has actually happened.

Comment: I did finally figure that out. I ended up writing a separate function to handle the window.open() and window.close() methods.